# ')' Expected, illegal start of expression

Tags: java

I'm getting errors like this:

```
Test. java:8 :')' expected
Test. java: 8: error :illegal start of expression
Test. java:9 :')' expected
Test. java: 9: error :illegal start of expression
```

Lines 8 and 9 are:

```
blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(BlackJackHand playerhand);
blackjackdealer = checkForBlackJacks(BlackJackHand dealerhand);
```

The class is:

```
  public class Test{
        public void playround (){
                int temp = -1;
                playerhand = new BlackJackHand(22);
                dealerhand = new BlackJackHand(22);
                addCards(playerhand, 2);
                addCards(dealerhand, 2);
                blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(BlackJackHand playerhand);
                blackjackdealer = checkForBlackJacks(BlackJackHand dealerhand);
                while(temp!=2&&playerhand.gettotal()<=21){
                    printHands(false, true, true);
                    temp = Prompt.getInt("\nPress 1 to hit, or 2 to stand. ", 1, 2);
                    if (temp==1&&playerhand.gettotal()<=21){
                        addCards(playerhand,1);
                    }
                }
                if (playerhand.gettotal()>21){
                    playerbust = true;
                }
                else{
                    seeWhoWon();
                }
                    //done = true;
        }
        public boolean checkForBlackJacks (BlackJackHand x){
            return (x.gettotal()==21&&x.getmyhand().size()==2);
        }
    }
```

This is just a java file with the error parts in it.  The real program has all the components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a value as a method parameter, you must only include the object's name, not its type.

```
blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(playerhand);
blackjackdealer = checkForBlackJacks(dealerhand);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I feel kind of silly for forgetting that.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sleep then ;) Anyway, glad to have helped. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Change the lines to

```
blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(playerhand);
blackjackdealer = checkForBlackJacks(dealerhand);
```

You just need to pass the already created object name. No need to use class name.

Answer (score 1):

It is plainly a syntax error.  A method call looks like this:

```
blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(playerhand);
```

not this

```
blackjackplayer = checkForBlackJacks(BlackJackHand playerhand);
```

---

If you look at the character position for the error message, it is most likely at position of the `playerHand` symbol ... and it is telling you that it is expecting THAT symbol to be a `')'`.  If you don't understand an error message, it often helps to try and read it in a literal sense ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to say BlackJackHand playerHand in those lines. Just playerHand will do.

Comment: Not "you don't need to", you *cannot*.